# Dracaena Fragrans Grafting?

Tags: houseplants, plant-health, pruning, plant-care, office-gardening

Our office Dracaena Fragrans (called Wilson) is not healthy looking. The stalk of the plant is beige, woody and completely dried out. Once it was cut (before my time) a new stalk developed. This is also turning beige at the bottom.

Is there a way of transplanting the healthy portion and growing roots on the appendage of the original dead woody stalk? (perhaps something like a Dieffenbachia plant, which you can graft to grow new roots)

Comment: Pictures would be a big plus.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, in good light the Mass Cane, or [Dracaena massangea](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Dracaena_fragrans) as it is also called propagates readily without grafting.

If the stem has died you take a sharp knife or sequiteur and cut off the healthy portion.  All of the methods below have worked for me:

- if the stem is over six inches you can plunge it into a soil less mix and provide light and water
- stems also root readily in water in a jar.  When the roots are three inches long or so move to a soil less mix
- placing the stem in a rooting medium such as moist perlite or vermiculite and moving to a soil less mix

Rooting in water in bright diffuse light is very practical and foolproof as long as the cutting is in good shape.